# Javascript this confusion

Tags: javascript

```
function StringBuffer(initialStr) {
    this.append(initialStr);
}
StringBuffer.prototype = {
    items: [],
    append: function(str) {
        this.items[this.items.length] = str instanceof StringBuffer ? str.toString() : str;
        return this;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return this.items.join("");
    }
};
alert(new StringBuffer("foo").append(new StringBuffer("bar")).toString());
```

How do I make sure this alerts "foobar" ?

Comment: Why are you making a string buffer?

Comment: Use this.items.push in append function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an instance `items` attribute, not shared:

```
function StringBuffer(initialStr) {
    this.items = [];
    this.append(initialStr);
}
```

and remove it from prototype.

Otherwise all the instances of `StringBuffer` mutate the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Make `items` an instance variable instead of an array that is shared by all StringBuffer instances.

```
function StringBuffer(initialStr) {
    this.items = [];
    this.append(initialStr);
}
StringBuffer.prototype = {
    append: function(str) {
        this.items[this.items.length] = str instanceof StringBuffer ? str.toString() : str;
        return this;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return this.items.join("");
    }
};
```